# django query annotate values get list from reverse foreign key

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have a simple model like

```
class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name



class Blog(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Here I want to queryall authors with the title of all the blogs they have written like

```
Author One : [Blog One, Blog Two, Blog Three]
```

I want this from query and not loop

Here my approach is to use subquery like

```
blogs =Blog.objects.filter(author=OuterRef('pk')).values("title")
authors = Author.objects.annotate(blogs=Subquery(blogs), output_field=CharField())
```

But here I am getting error like `sub-select returns 2 columns - expected 1`

How can I get all the authors with all the blogs they have written ? I do not want to use loop. I want this through query

Comment: Eventually it will go through a loop that will make a list. Usually it is *not* a good idea to do string processing in the database.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem its ok if not string. I works for me if it is list. Updated the question

Comment: but the same comment holds for a list or any other collection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using a `postgres` as a database, then you can use an `ArrayAgg` function:

```
from django.contrib.postgres.aggregates import ArrayAgg

authors = Author.objects.annotate(blogs=ArrayAgg('blog_set__title'))
```

Comment: great.. just the thing is you can only do ArrayAgg('blog__title')).. you dont need set here.. thank you

Comment: @GreenPanda hi, mark the post as resolved, if it really helped you, thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can query with:

```
authors = Author.objects.prefetch_related('blog_set')
```

Then in the template, you can render with:

```
<ul>
  {% for author in authors %}
    <li>{{ author }}</li>
    <ul>
      {% for blog in author.blog_set.all %}
        <li>{{ blog }}</li>
      {% endfor %}
    </ul>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: I dont need this in template.. I just want the result of query in list